# Are Database duplication and Mirroring one and the same?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, replication, mirroring, duplication

I am going over the concepts of Distributed database management system. I read about duplication and replication. Then there is also something called Mirroring. I googled to find if duplication is the same as mirroring but could not find. Are they same?

How is duplication different from snapshot replication?

Comment: Database duplication is like making a copy of the database at a single point of time. Any changes made after duplicating on source will not flow to the copy. Whereas in mirroring, the changes will flow depending on your configuration/settings.

Comment: Your title asks something different than the question. Are you interested in mirroring or snapshot replication? What do you mean by "duplication" anyway. This isn't a term used to mean anything specific in SQL Server. Do you have a precise definition in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Duplicate Database

It is separate database contains all or subset of the data of Source Database.

Its purpose varies like:

- Test backup/recovery procedure
- Test upgrade of new release
- Test effect of DB performance
- Generate reports
- Export data table and import in production environment if inadvertently dropped

#### Snapshot Replication

Here data is replicated at specified time by copying data changes from Source Database (Publisher) to receiving database (Subscriber)

Its purpose varies like:

- If data change is infrequent
- If database is of small size or data change occurs in large amount